# Setting arguments to fragment causes IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, illegalstateexception

I am setting arguments to fragments inflated from XML using the following code:

```
  fragment_phone=(AddNewFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.I'd.phone_fragment);
   Bundle args=fragment_phone.getArguments();
    if(args==null)
    {
        args=new Bundle();
        args.putString("hint","Phone");
        fragment_phone.set arguments(args);
      }
      else
            args.putString("hint","Phone");

   //Similarly for two other fragments that are also instances of AddNewFragment
```

I use three `Bundle` objects,one for each fragment.
The Logcat says `Fragment is already active java.lang.IllegalStateException at android.support.v4.app.setArguments`

I have tried removing `setArguments` which causes `NullPointerException` when  I call this:

```
    Bundle args=get arguments();
    String hint=args.getString("hint");
    Log.d(TAG," Hint :"+hint);
```

Comment: You can't set arguments for fragments defined in the xml layout.

Comment: Then how can I pass them any values,can I do it when defining in XML

Comment: Not in the xml. You can add them manually and use the Bundles with setArguments() or you could call setter methods on them(but you'll need to save the data yourself as that will not be automatically saved as it is with arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Fragments you always have to implement an `interface`.

1. Create the `interface` in the fragment which is to communicate with the other fragment.
2. Implement the `interface` in your `MainActivity` or the `Activity` class.
3. Call on the `getArguments` in the `onActivityCreated()` to avoid any `NullPointerExceptions`.

For more see [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Comment: I would like to use the fragment's resource id in the interface callback so that I can get the values for each instance correctly...Is there a way to get resource id from FragmentManager or something else.